# problem with rendering an object property from API object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have requested API call in my Recipe App and have access to all the data I need in my front page but then when I try to to get specific properties from the API call in another page of my app I get an error once I try to render it. 
I get an error telling me "Unable to get property 'label' of undefined or null reference"
could someone please help?

**This is my code**:

***RecipeApp***

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Form from "./components/form";
import Recipes from "./components/Recipes";
import "./App.css";

export default class RecipeApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    recipes: []
  };

  getRecipe = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const recipeName = event.target.recipeName.value;

    const API_CALL = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${recipeName}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=10&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`
    );

    const data = await API_CALL.json();
    this.setState({
      recipes: data.hits
    });
    console.log(this.state.recipes);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <h1>Find Your Recipe</h1>
        </header>
        <Form getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
        <Recipes
          recipes={this.state.recipes}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

***Router***

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import RecipeApp from "../recipe-app"
import Recipe from "./Recipe"

const Router = () => {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={RecipeApp} exact/>
       <Route path="/recipe/:label" component={Recipe} />
     </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter> 
    )
}

export default Router
```

***Recipes***

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const Recipes = ({ recipes }) => (
    <div id="container">
        <div className="row">
        {recipes.map( (item) => {
         return(
           <div  key={item.recipe.label} className="col-md-4" style={{marginBottom: "2rem"}}>
             <div id="item-box">
               <img 
                 src={item.recipe.image} 
                 alt={item.recipe.label} />
                 <div id="item-text">
                 <h3>{item.recipe.label.length > 20 ? `${item.recipe.label}` : `${item.recipe.label.substring(0, 25)}...`}</h3>
                 <p><i>publisher: {item.recipe.source}</i></p>
               </div>
                 <button>
                   <Link 
                     to={ {
                      pathname: `/recipe/${item.recipe.label}`,
                      state: { recipe: item.recipe.label }
                     } }>view recipe
                   </Link>
                </button>
             </div>
           </div>
         )  
         })} 
        </div>  
    </div> 
)

export default Recipes;
```

***Recipe***

```
import React from "react" 

class Recipe extends React.Component {

    state = {
        activeRecipe: []
    }

     componentDidMount = async () => {

    const title = this.props.location.state.recipe

    const request = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${title}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`
    );

    const response = await request.json();
    this.setState({ activeRecipe: response.hits[0] })
   }

    render() {
        const recipe = this.state.activeRecipe
        console.log(recipe.recipe.label)
        return(
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default Recipe
```

This is Error Message:

````
The above error occurred in the <Recipe> component:
    in Recipe (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at Router.js:11)
    in Switch (at Router.js:9)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at Router.js:8)
    in Router (at src/index.js:7)

SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'label' of undefined or null reference
main.chunk.js (115,5)

0: Unable to get property 'label' of undefined or null reference```
````

Comment: You need to check for the label before rendering it. `{ item.recipe.label && item.recipe.label }`

Answer (score 0):

Because when component starts, the recipes state is = []. The API that you call to the server is Async. At the first time render of Component, this API still not yet return data for you, for the second time, you will got this data.

At here: `{recipes.map( (item) => { })}`, recipes empting in the first time render of Component, so when you access to `item.recipe.label`. You will got the error `Unable to get property 'label' of undefined or null`.

To resolve this, make sure recipes has data like this:

```
recipes.length > 0 && recipes.map( (item) => { ... })
```

Or you can use default parameter like this:

```
{recipes.map( (item) => {
   const { recipe = {} } = item; 
   // use default parameter here to make sure recipe always is an object
   // then, use recipe.label will be no errors
   return(
       <div  key={recipe.label} className="col-md-4" style={{marginBottom: "2rem"}}>
       ...
       </div>
   )  
})}
```

Comment: So the RECIPES components works fine and the bunch of recipes are showing just fine. The problem occurs when I try to click the button in the specific recipe in the recipes component which should take me to that RECIPE component and render example {recipe.recipe.label}.

Comment: @JariSedergren You should be check `recipe` is not empty array before render in `Recipe Component`. Example: `recipe.recipe && console.log(recipe.recipe.label)`